# How to get close event from the opener in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

I was investigating and reading about that and couldn't find anywhere how it should be done.

I am developing a *chrome extension* taking for reference the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

So I want to create a popup and listen when it closes as in the code snippet below ( that is not working ).

```
chrome.windows.create({
   url: "http://www.google.com",
   type: "popup",
   width: 640,
   height: 800
}, function(w) {
   w.onunload = function () {
      console.log("hey");
   };
});
```

Any suggestion about how is the best way it should be done?

Comment: See the documentation for chrome.windows API: the window parameter is not a DOM window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to `chrome.windows.onRemoved` event will work but I couldn't find any better way to identify the popup id but the scope of the closure.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function () {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        type: "popup",
        width: 640,
        height: 800
    }, function(w) {
        chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (wIndex) {
            if (wIndex === w.id) {
                console.log("hey");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Given that you can only have the window close once, you should remove your listener when you detect the window close.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to keep track of the popup window id and check that variable in the `chrome.windows.onRemoved` listener, so you don't have to add and remove listeners everytime:

```
var myPopupId;

chrome.windows.create({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    type: "popup",
    width: 640,
    height: 800
    }, function(w) {
        myPopupId = w.id;
    }
);

chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId){
    if (windowId == myPopupId){
        console.log("hey");
    }
});
```